# How to run linker after emitting LLVM object file

Tags: llvm

I wrote a simple toy language compiler frontend that generates LLVM IR using [llvm-sys](https://crates.io/crates/llvm-sys) (Rust bindings for LLVM's [C library](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMC.html)). I then generated an object file by creating a `LLVMTargetMachine` based on the machine's target triple then calling `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile`, which successfully generates an executable. However, running the executable produces `zsh: exec format error: ./a.out`.

I figured out that I had to run `ld -lSystem ./a.out` after generating the executable to make it work. How should I automatically call the linker in code?

Currently using LLVM 9.0 on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile` produces an object file that still needs to be **linked** - either into an executable or shared library.

You need a linker for this, which is not, strictly speaking, a part of LLVM. LLVM's integrated linker operates on LLVM IR, not native machine code.

However, just like there is a LLVM-related C compiler, Clang, there also is a LLVM-related native linker called LLD. AFAIK, it can be used as a library, so you can imbue your compiler with integrated linked.

It worth noting that native compilers follow "pipeline" architecture, where the compiler itself and linker (and sometimes assembler too) are completely decoupled one from other. In such architecture, the compiler executable (like `clang` or `g++`) is actually a **driver** program that invokes other programs (`cc1`, the real compiler and `ld`, the linker) to produce the final binary.